# extract information from non tabular file and store as tibble

Tags: r, tibble

I used a statical library which exported its output in text file. I wish to extract some information from the text file. I can copy-paste, but I want to automate this process of extracting information from output text file.

Below is an sample output in text file.

How do extract LL(0) and LL(final) and corresponding values and store them in tibble?

Thanks

```
Date: XX-XX-XXXX
Time: XX:XX PM

Model: Binary Logit Model

LL(0)                            : -376.3789
Number of Inputs                 :  500
LL(final)                        : -114.1382
Rho-sq                           :  0.512
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can read the `.txt` with `readLines`, use `grep` to subset the lines that have "LL", extract the numeric component with a regex by removing characters until the `:` followed by zero or more spaces

```
v1 <- sub(".*:\\s*", "", grep("^LL\\(", txt, value = TRUE))
tibble(v1 = as.numeric(v1))
# A tibble: 2 x 1
#    v1
#  <dbl>
#1 -376.
#2 -114.
```

---

If we want the header as well

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
read.table(text = grep("^LL\\(", txt, value = TRUE), 
        sep = ":", strip.white = TRUE) %>% 
     data.table::transpose(., make.names = "V1")
#     LL(0) LL(final)
#1 -376.3789 -114.1382
```

#### data

```
txt <- readLines('file.txt')
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following will do what the question asks for. The parenthesis must be escaped in order for `grep` to get them.

```
library(tibble)

fun_extract <- function(text, pattern){
  i <- grep(pattern, text)
  x <- sub("^.*:(.*$)", "\\1", text[i])
  as.numeric(x)
}

lines <- readLines("data.txt")

ll0 <- "LL\\(0\\)"
llfinal <- "LL\\(final\\)"

tbl <- tibble(
  `LL(0)` = fun_extract(lines, ll0), 
  `LL(final)` = fun_extract(lines, llfinal)
)
```